# Umbraco external URL redirect

Tags: url, xslt, external, umbraco

I've added a textstring property "externalURL" to my Doctype. I want to enter in the external URL in the textstring and for that link to redirect to the external URL when that link is clicked within the nav.

However the following isn't working:

```
<a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="string(externalUrl) != ''">
               <xsl:value-of select="externalUrl" />
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)" />
             </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@id = $currentPage/@id]">
           <xsl:attribute name="class">current</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
       </a>
```

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple matter of case sensitivity. I needed to change "externalUrl" to "externalURL" to match my property type. Sometimes it's the most obvious things.

Comment: JV10, can you please share the full XSLT file? I am also working on adding an external url redirect to my Umbraco site.